# AJAX-refresh behaviour to the feedback panel Only

Tags: java, wicket

I have a form that will uload files. The page have a FeedBackPanel. For some reasone, the UploadProgressBar is not working for me. Is there some way to add AJAX-refresh behaviour to the feedback panel only? That way I can have atleast an info() in the feedbackpanel when upload is over.
Thanks

Comment: In case of your not working UploadProgressBar: have you in your `WebApplication` set `getApplicationSettings().setUploadProgressUpdatesEnabled(true);` ?

Comment: yes I did try that already

Answer (score 0):

You could `send()` an event after upload finished and receive it in the FeedbackPanel in `onEvent()`. The event should contain an AjaxRequestTarget so you can add the feedbackPanel to it.

Comment: Can you elabotate a bit Robert?

Comment: Well i looked a bit more and i found this: http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/ajax/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.source.SourcesPage?5&SourcesPage_class=org.apache.wicket.examples.ajax.builtin.FileUploadPage - It should be exactly your use case. In the forms `onSubmit` you got the `info()` messages added and then the `AjaxSubmitButton` add's the `FeedbackPanel` to the `AjaxRequestTarget` which should then render your message.

Comment: Tried that solution already! The problem is, the FeedBackPanel display the messages once all of the documents (multiple document upload) are finished uploaded.

Comment: add(new AjaxButton("import")
            {
                @Override
                public void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form)
                {
                    uploadedFiles = fileUpload.getFileUploads();
                    if (isNotEmpty(uploadedFiles)) {
                        for (FileUpload documentToUpload : uploadedFiles) {
     ... Do Uploads
                            info("File [" + fileName + "] is written successfully!");
     target.add(feedbackPanel());

                        }
                    }
                }
            });